# Scrolling to top after refreshed with mCustomScrollbar jquery how to prevent it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Drag  on scrolling set to scroll so that user can scroll, but when the refresh happens the scrolling goes back to the top. Any ideas how I can keep the scroll position after the page  is refreshed?

```
{literal}
        (function($){
            $(window).load(function(){
                /* custom scrollbar fn call */

                $(".content_2").mCustomScrollbar({
                    scrollInertia:150;,
                    theme:"light";
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);
{/literal}
```

You can see image here[image]

Comment: There are alot of ways for doing this,first show your HTML , or make a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Set it in localstorage and retrieve it on window load:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    // load custom scrollbar here...
    var _top = localStorage.getItem('scrollPosition') || 0;
    $('html, body').scrollTop(_top);
});

$(window).on('scroll', function (e) {
    localStorage.setItem('scrollPosition', $(this).scrollTop());
});
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/G5uFr/

Comment: Your code is working fine with systmen scroller but i am using mCustomScrollbar jquery and its not working